# Unable to invoke node.js when html button is clicked?

Tags: html, node.js, ajax

I created a html page with 2 buttons.When I click these buttons I want to invoke a node.js file.Currently when I click this button nothing is happening. When I inspected the page in chrome it showed

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I have already installed express using the command `npm install -g express`.I am running this on an apache2 server on ubuntu.I have copied both the html and nodejs file to `var/www/html` directory.

I have made use of express framework and I am communicating with the nodejs file using an ajax request.

web.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<h3>Example of a Deploy And Decommission Button</h3> 
<body> 
<button onclick="myFunction()" >Deploy</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Decommission</button>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script >
function myFunction() {
  $.post("/createContainer").done(() => {
   console.log("container created")
  });
}
</script>        


</body> 
</html>
```

node.js file

```
const app = require("express")();
    const process = require('child_process');
    app.post("/createContainer", (req, res) => {
     process.exec('kubectl apply -f tomcat.yaml',function (err,stdout,stderr) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("\n"+stderr);
      } else {
        console.log(stdout);
      }
    });
   });
   app.list(80);
```

What changes do I have to make to my code if any.I heard that node.js will run on its own node server which brings me to my next question of how to run both the html page and nodejs on the same server.

I mean i am really confused about how I will run this app. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

If you're running localhost then you need the full url:

```
http://localhost:{port}/createContainer
```

Comment: OP is not able to run node js server and it means there is no endpoint he can call.

Answer (score -1):

First thing first apache2 and express.js are two separate servers. So you can use both of them but it would be wise to choose only one of them.

In your example you would to do two things, serve your html file and connect your application with an endpoint.

In express.js you are able to serve your html file.

Without running any apache2 server you can run your nodejs application which is working with express.js server.

**public/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <h3>Example of a Deploy And Decommission Button</h3>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Deploy</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Decommission</button>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        $.post("/createContainer").done(data => {
          console.log("container created");
          console.log(data);
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const process = require("child_process");
const path = require("path");

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/index.html"));
});
app.post("/createContainer", (req, res) => {
  process.exec("kubectl apply -f tomcat.yaml", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("\n" + stderr);
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      console.log(stdout);
      res.send(stdout);
    }
  });
});
app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log("Listening on port 8080!");
});
```

And you need to run your application

```
node src/index.js
```

You can check from https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-forest-4dvcy

Comment: Check this example https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-forest-4dvcy and export as a ZIP. You need your package.json and express.js dependency in it.

Comment: Hi the deploy button is working now but i want the decommision button to run the command 'kubectl delete pods,services,deployments,pvc,pv --all' so i changed the code accordingly but the decommision button is giving Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED or connection refused